# User with one badge, but can't see any in user page?

Tags: support, badges, profile-page, caching

I'm a [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com) reviewer, and spend a lot of time greeting new users using the wonderful [SE-AutoReviewComments](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments) to give boilerplate encouraging comments. One of my big questions is whether they've taken the Tour; if not, I end the comment with:

> And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

So, whenever a user has one or more badges, I'll check to see whether one of them is "Informed" (taken the tour).

Once in a while, though, I'll get a new user with one badge, but the profile page shows no badges. In a recent example, new user [Phena Wilson Phillips](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/104041/phena-wilson-phillips) has the following badge display on their profile page:

[image: One badge, but none to display]

What's up with this? Are there obscure (or perhaps non-"rare") badges that won't be displayed on a profile page? Is this some sort of server bug or time lag between badge acquisition and display? Can I be sure that this hidden badge isn't "Informed"?

**Edit**: in the fifty minutes since I first posted this question, the user's one badge has become visible on their profile page:

[image: Now shows "student" badge]

So, there's some time-dependent thing going on in the server. Any ideas what?

Comment: Classic cache issue )

Comment: Don't worry, someone with some boilerplate will be by with your answer shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this seems to be a caching issue; no matter how often you reload a new (and affected) user's profile page, you won't see the actual badge earned (until some timer expires, which can take a number of minutes, which is forever when you're trying to cruise through the reviews).

I have, however, found a workaround:

1. Go to the user's network profile
2. Click the "activity" tab
3. Look at the history; you'll see the badge being awarded, and its type.

So, here's hoping SE fixes this, but there's a way around it.

Comment: Nothing to fix, it's a server side cache used to make the profile page load faster. Those few who really want "real time" data can use the workaround you suggested.